# enabling hsts for node byproxy with nginx not working

Tags: node.js, nginx

My webserver hosted on AWS with nodejs and i am using aws ELB for http -> https re-direction adn it handles the ssl, but in my webserver nodejs is byproxy by nginx, so i am trying to enable HSTS on /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. but it is not working.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com www.google.com google.com gstatic.com www.gstatic.com connect.facebook.net facebook.com;";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what “not working” means

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running certbot with the --hsts flag.

```sh
certbot --nginx --hsts
```

Then that strict-transport-security header came up